# Select (Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement)

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I am having problem on my code I wanted to check the duplicate ID inside pipeline process_item, if there's no duplicate id I will insert the items inside the table

here's my code

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, GPHM):
        t = (item['hm_title'],)
        rows_affected = self.curr.execute('SELECT 
COUNT(hm_articode) from saleitems_hm WHERE hm_articode=?', t)
        rows_affected = self.curr.rowcount

        if rows_affected > 1:
            global item_countHM 
            item_countHM += 1
            self.store_db(item)
    return item


def store_db(self, item):
    self.curr.execute("""insert into saleitems_hm values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", (
            item['1'],
            item['2'],
            item['3'],
            item['4'],
            item['5'],
            item['6']
        ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Any Idea please?

Answer (score 2):

The `SELECT count(*) FROM TBL WHERE` statement in the SQL returns only 1 row i.e the count of all the rows in the result set. Now review this part of code:

```
rows_affected = self.curr.execute('SELECT 
COUNT(hm_articode) from saleitems_hm WHERE hm_articode=?', t)
rows_affected = self.curr.rowcount

if rows_affected > 1:
    global item_countHM 
    item_countHM += 1
    self.store_db(item)
```

rowcount returns the affected number of rows which will be 1 or -1 in this case. The row_affected will never be greater the one and code under the if condition will never be executed. You can use [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) to get the actual count. Check the code below:

```
r = self.curr.fetchone('SELECT 
COUNT(hm_articode) from saleitems_hm WHERE hm_articode= %s', t)
is_duplicate = r[0] > 1

if not is_duplicate:
    global item_countHM 
    item_countHM += 1
    self.store_db(item)
```

Note that if condition is changed as you want to insert for non duplicate records. `Count(*)` is greater than 1 for duplicate records.

Comment: Hi @joshi I tried your code and I am still getting the error self.curr.execute('SELECT COUNT(hm_articode) from saleitems_hm WHERE hm_articode=?', t) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Comment: try to use %s for string formatting. Check the edited code.